# mandelbrot image creation using pthread

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, pthreads, mandelbrot

i am getting an error: invalid lvalue in assignment.

this is the only error with my program, it looks like a fatal compile time error regards on specially pthread.

i am trying to get the inputs in the runtime, using command line arguments, that's why i am getting an error, but previously i didn't get any error, when i run the program in static input initialized in the program itself.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define num_threads 8
pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
unsigned int width = 1500;
unsigned int height = 1500;
unsigned int max_iterations = 30000;
unsigned int **color = NULL;
double min_re;
double max_re;
double min_im;
double max_im;
double x_factor;
double y_factor;
unsigned int NUM_OF_THREADS;
int chunk = 10;
int total_sum = 0;

bool file_write()
{
FILE *fractal = fopen("mandelbrot_imagepthread.ppm","w+");
if(fractal != NULL)
{
 fprintf(fractal,"P6\n");
    fprintf(fractal,"# %s\n", "Mandelbrot_imagepthread.ppm");
    fprintf(fractal,"%d %d\n", height, width);
    fprintf(fractal,"255\n");

 int y = 0, x = 0;
 unsigned int R = 0, G = 0, B = 0;
 for(x = 0; x < width; ++x)
 {
    for(y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
         R = (color[y][x]*10)%255;
            G = 255-((color[y][x]*10)%255);
            B = ((color[y][x]*10)-150)%255;
      if(R == 10) R = 11;
      if(G == 10) G = 11;
      if(B == 10) B = 11;
            putc(R, fractal);
            putc(G, fractal);
            putc(B, fractal);
    }
 }
 fclose(fractal);
 }
 return true;
}
int method(int x, int y, int max_iterations, double max_im,double min_re,double x_factor, double y_factor)
{
    double c_im = max_im - y*y_factor;
    double c_re = min_re + x*x_factor;
    double Z_re = c_re, Z_im = c_im;
    unsigned int col = 0;
    for(unsigned n=0; n<max_iterations; ++n)
        {
            double Z_re2 = Z_re*Z_re, Z_im2 = Z_im*Z_im;
            if(Z_re2 + Z_im2 > 4)
                {
                    col = n;
                    break;
                }
                    Z_im = 2 * Z_re * Z_im + c_im;
                    Z_re = Z_re2 - Z_im2 + c_re;
        }
    return col;
}
void* method1(void* t)
{
double min_re = -2.0;
double max_re = 1.0;
double min_im = -1.2;
double max_im = min_im+(max_re-min_re)*height/width;
double x_factor = (max_re-min_re)/(width-1);
double y_factor = (max_im-min_im)/(height-1);
int x,y;
int sub_total = -1;
pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
if(total_sum < height)
{
    sub_total = total_sum;
    total_sum = total_sum + chunk;
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
while(sub_total > -1)
{
    int start_point = sub_total;
    int end_point = start_point + chunk;
    for(y=start_point; y<end_point; y++)
    {
        for(x=0; x<width; ++x)
        {
            int m1;
            uintptr_t m2;
            m2 = (uintptr_t)t;
            m1 = method(x,y,max_iterations,max_im,min_re,x_factor,y_factor);
            if(m1)
            {
                color[x][y] = m1*40;
            } 
        }
    }
    sub_total = -1;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    if(total_sum < height)
    {
        sub_total = total_sum;
        total_sum = total_sum + chunk;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
}
  pthread_exit((void*)&t);
} 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if(argc != 9)
{
printf("There is an error in the input given.\n");
return 0;
}
else
{
   height = atoi(argv[1]);
   width = atoi(argv[2]);
max_iterations = atoi(argv[3]);
min_re = atof(argv[4]);
max_re = atof(argv[5]);
min_im = atof(argv[6]);
max_im = atof(argv[7]);
num_threads = atoi(argv[8]);
}
color = (unsigned int**)malloc(height*sizeof(unsigned int*));
x_factor = (max_re-min_re)/(width-1);
y_factor = (max_im-min_im)/(height-1);
printf("height = %d\twidth = %d\tmaximum_iterations = %d\tminimum_x-value = %.2f\tmaximum_x-value = %.2f\tminimum_y-value = %.2f\tmaximum_y-value = %.2f\tno. of threads = %d\t\n",height,width,max_iterations,min_re,max_re,min_im,max_im,num_threads);
int x;
for(x = 0; x < height; x++)
{
color[x] = (unsigned int*)malloc(width*sizeof(unsigned int));
}
time_t ts,te;
time(&ts);
pthread_t t1[num_threads];
pthread_attr_t attr;
int l1;
void *att;
double value = 0.0;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
for(int i=0;i<num_threads;i++)
{
    l1 = pthread_create(&t1[i], &attr, method1, (void *) i);
    if(l1)
    {
        printf("There is some kind of error in thread creation: %d", l1);
        exit(-1);
    }
}
pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
for(int i=0;i<num_threads;i++)
{
    l1 = pthread_join(t1[i],&att);
    if(l1)
    {
        printf("There is some kind of error in thread creation: %d", l1);
        exit(-1);
    }
    double result = *(double *)att;
    value += result;
 }
time(&te);
double diff = difftime(te,ts);
file_write();
printf("Total Time elapsed: %.2f seconds\n",diff);
for(x = 0; x < height; x++)
{
    free(color[x]);
}
free(color);
return 0;
pthread_exit(NULL);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error here is that you define num_threads to be 8 with a #define directive instead declaring it as int!
Change `#define num_threads 8` to `int num_threads=8;`

In general you should avoid `#define` directives because they are evil.
If you want to have a global constant variables declare it as `static const` rather than a `#define`. Those directives are substituted by the preprocessor to the following code and lead to the following (non-sense) code.

`8 = atoi(argv[8])`